# contour plot in bokeh

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, bokeh

I would like to use `pyplot.contour` feature in `bokeh`. Is there any way I can use it?? [image: Matplotlib Contour Example] I know `pyplot.pcolormesh` and `bokeh.plotting.image`. Can I use conotur plot with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pyplot.contour` is part of Matplotlib, not Bokeh. As of Bokeh 2.3.0 there is no built-in contouring function or capability. Recently a `MultiPolygons` glyph that can support "polygons with holes" was added. This is a first necessary step to being able to have real contour plots in Bokeh. A next step would be for someone to write a set of functions that can accept array inputs and generate the multi-polygon data necessary to drive Bokeh graphics, but this has not been done by anyone yet.

If image contour plots (similar to `pcolormesh`) or line (unfilled) contours suit your needs, that you can consider using Holoviews, which can generate Bokeh contour plots for those kinds of cases:

http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Contours.html